# Error: “Wrapper object use after free (WRAPPER_ESCAPE)”

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, free, coverity

```
...
Object& a = list.front();
list.pop_front();
...
```

I need to use &a after doing the above. But coverity is raising the use after free issue. Is using &a after doing pop_front() a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
Object& a = list.front();
```

you make `a` *reference* the front element of the list. When you later pop the front element, it is destructed leaving you with a reference to a non-existing object.

You should *copy* the element instead

```
Object a = list.front();
```

Or possibly *move* it

```
Object a = std::move(list.front());
```